# Ошибка обращения к базе SQL

Tags: php, sql

Имеется сервер. На нем установлена поддержка .php и предоставлен доступ к базе mysql.

### Подключаюсь к базе вот так:

```
$SQLhost='sub.domain.net';
$SQLuser='user';
$SQLpass='password';
$SQLdbase='DBase';

$mysqli = new mysqli($SQLhost, $SQLuser, $SQLpass, $SQLdbase);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Unable to connect to MySQL: ('.$mysqli->connect_errno.')'.$mysqli->connect_error;
}

$query='SELECT * FROM WORDS'; // <<<<<<<<<<<<< WORDS - a sheet of DBase

$res = $mysqli->query($query);

if($res!=FALSE) {
    $res->data_seek(0);
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo 'id='.$row['id'].'<br>';
    }
}
else printf('Error: %s\n', $mysqli->error);
```

Подключается к базе без ошибок.
При выводе всей базы все нормально выполняется и выводится, но когда пытаюсь усложнить запрос, то `$res` возвращает `FALSE`.
Усложненный запрос выглядит вот так:

```
$query='SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE FIELD("31.12.2018",`AddDate`,`1`)';
```

`1` и `AddDate` - столбцы таблицы `WORDS`, в которых эта дата есть.
Проверял непосредственно на сайте через встроенный интерфейс - любой запрос работает, а с моей страницы программно не хочет..
Пишет ошибку:

> Error: Unknown column 'AddDate' in 'where clause'\n

Что очень удивительно, т.к. этот столбец существует.

Comment: Раз он вернул false значит ошибка все таки была и стоило бы напечатать ее из http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php что бы понять что происходит

Comment: обычно пишут FIELD IN (VALUE1,VALUE2)

Comment: Ваш запрос содержит и апостроф, и двойные кавычки, и одинарные кавычки. Вы салат делаете или SQL запрос? В первый раз вижу такие конструкции в PHP.